# Why is my php scipt running before input

Tags: php, html

I am very new to php coming from c# I am currently working on a whois module for a website. The problem I am having is when I browse to my php page It automatically runs, posting the message "invalid input" before I even click the button. Why is this? Thank you for any help

```
    ..Php code to do lookup?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Whois Lookup Script</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<form action="whois.php">
<p>
<b><label for="domain">Domain/IP Address:</label></b>
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain">
 <input type="submit" value="Lookup">
</p>
</form>
<?php
if($domain) {
    $domain = trim($domain);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 7) == "http://") $domain = substr($domain, 7);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 4) == "www.") $domain = substr($domain, 4);
    if(ValidateIP($domain)) {
        echo "hello before check";
        $result = LookupIP($domain);
    }
    elseif(ValidateDomain($domain)) {
        $result = LookupDomain($domain);
    }
    else die("Invalid Input!");
    echo "<pre>\n" . $result . "\n</pre>\n";
}


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: php runs serverside on page load- thats how php works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test whether the script is being run to display the form the first time or is being run due to submitting the form.

When you submit the form, the value in the `domain` input will be put into `$_GET['domain']`. So check whether this is set:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['domain'])) {
    $domain = trim($_GET['domain']);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 7) == "http://") $domain = substr($domain, 7);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 4) == "www.") $domain = substr($domain, 4);
    if(ValidateIP($domain)) {
        echo "hello before check";
        $result = LookupIP($domain);
    }
    elseif(ValidateDomain($domain)) {
        $result = LookupDomain($domain);
    }
    else die("Invalid Input!");
    echo "<pre>\n" . $result . "\n</pre>\n";
}
```

Comment: I think its being run to display the form because after I added that code to verify there is a value It displays no error or "invalid input" but does not work anymore. The url is appended though

Comment: I had a typo, `$_GET['$domain']` shouldn't have `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Whois Lookup Script</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<form action="whois.php" method="POST">
<p>
<b><label for="domain">Domain/IP Address:</label></b>
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain">
 <input type="submit" value="Lookup">
</p>
</form>
<?php
$domain = $_POST['domain'];
if(!empty($domain)) {
    $domain = trim($domain);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 7) == "http://") $domain = substr($domain, 7);
    if(substr(strtolower($domain), 0, 4) == "www.") $domain = substr($domain, 4);
    if(ValidateIP($domain)) {
        echo "hello before check";
        $result = LookupIP($domain);
            echo "<pre>\n" . $result . "\n</pre>\n";
    }
    elseif(ValidateDomain($domain)) {
        $result = LookupDomain($domain);
            echo "<pre>\n" . $result . "\n</pre>\n";
    }
    else{ 
    die("Invalid Input!");
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```